# Parsing HTML which is not valid XML

Tags: perl

I need to parse a website which has a lot of nested `<div>`s all over. I tried with `XML::Simple` to get a nice tree-structure, but the parse fails all the time because there seems to be two or three not closed `<p>` somewhere. I tried `HTML::Parser`, but that only lets me define some handler functions that give me the right tags, but not their nested elements.

There any way to get `XML::Simple` accept non-valid XML or `HTML::Parser` to give me a handy tree structure?

Comment: Try [Web::Scraper][] instead. [Web::Scraper]: http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Web::Scraper

Comment: Try [HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath](http://p3rl.org/HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath) instead.

Comment: HTML is not XML.  Why would you expect an XML parser to parse it?

Comment: @Wooble Because, at my heart, I wish it was.

Comment: An alternative to something based on [HTML::TreeBuilder][] is [XML::LibXML->load_html(...)][XML::LibXML::Parser load_html]. [HTML::TreeBuilder]: http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/HTML::TreeBuilder
[XML::LibXML::Parser load_html]: http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/XML::LibXML::Parser#DOM_Parser

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [HTML::TreeBuilder](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTML%3a%3aTreeBuilder) builds nice trees and gives tons of handy methods to traverse it.

Comment: The TreeBuilder did it for me. The server I am working on does not have XML::LibXML and I cannot install it. So many thanks for your help!

Comment: You can install it locally.

Answer (score 6):

An alternative to something based on [HTML::TreeBuilder](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/HTML%3a%3aTreeBuilder) is [XML::LibXML->load_html(...)](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/XML%3a%3aLibXML%3a%3aParser#DOM_Parser).

Answer (score 3):

But is it valid HTML? If so, [XML::LibXML](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/XML%3a%3aLibXML) will do a marvelous job if you use the HTML parsing functions. It is lightning fast and provides a great interface. It should even be able to handle some bad HTML using the `recover` option.

Alternatively, [HTML::Parser](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/HTML%3a%3aParser) (often used via [HTML::TreeBuilder](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/HTML%3a%3aTreeBuilder) or [HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/HTML%3a%3aTreeBuilder%3a%3aXPath)) is renown for handling bad HTML. It won't be as fast, though.